# How to connect my shop to public shopping portals/gateways?

Tags: shopify, e-commerce

I am thinking of building a store with some possible shop solutions, such as shopify. I am aiming at German speaking market, where the people like to use certain kind of "shopping portals" or "shopping gateways" (e.g., idealo.de, billiger.de) to initialize their buying behavior. In this regards, once I upload products into my own shop, I need those uploaded products also seachable from those "shopping portals"/"shopping gateways".

My question would be, normally how is the way to connect my store to those shopping portals/gateways? Is it also supported by some general shopping solutions (shopify or something else)?

Thanks!

Cheers, 
Ye

Answer (score 1):

Look into product search and price comparison feeds like those run by Google Base, Shopzilla, etc.

RetailTower and Versafeed are examples of apps that already do this.